# C++11 / g++ : std:: qualifier required in lambda, although "using namespace std" is given

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, c++11

I was trying to discover some of the goodies of the new C++11 standard (using g++ 4.6.2). Playing around with lambdas in a an "all_of" algorithm function, I encountered a strange problem with the std:: qualifier.

I am "using" the std namespace as shown at the beginning of the code snippet. This makes the declaration of the pair variable in the for loop well-defined.

However, I tried the same in the lambda argument used in the "all_of" algorithm. I came across several hard-to-understand error messages, before I realized that a full std:: qualified std::pair would work there, but only pair not.

Am I missing an important point? The declaration of the lambda happens in this file, so the namespace should still be active here, right? Or does the required std:: qualifier depend on some STL code in a different file? Or is it likely to be a bug in g++?

Best regards,
Peter

PS: the code compiles without warnings as pasted here, but removing the std:: in the all_of lambda, I get an error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

void duckburg() {

const int threshold = 100;
map <string, int> money;

money["donald"] = 200;
money["daisy"] = 400;
money["scrooge"] = 2000000;

// obviously, an "auto" type would work here nicely,
// but this way my problem is illustrated more clearly:

for (const pair <string, int> &pair : money) {
    cout << pair.first << "\t" << pair.second << endl;
}

if (all_of(money.begin(), money.end(),
    [&](std::pair<string, int> p) {
    return bool(p.second > threshold);
})) 
{
    cout << "yes, everyone is rich!";
} else {
    cout << "no, some are poor!";
};
}
```

Edit: Just noticed I received a downvote for this old question. No problem with that, but please elaborate on the reasons. It will help me improve future questions, and in the end the entire community will profit. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in GCC, compiles fine with MSVC 10. Can't test with Clang, as they do not implement lambdas yet. FWIW, GCC 4.5.1 has no problems with [this minimized code](http://ideone.com/LdGJT).

Comment: yes, I would have tested with/without the mentioned std:: in Clang myself, but for now it's impossible because of the missing lambdas.

Comment: You should make a version with all the unnecessary code removed, and provide the error message.

Comment: Try renaming the *variable* pair in your for loop. It's scope should only extend to the end of the for loop and therefore not interfere with your lambda, but g++ has or used to have compatibility code for ancient for-scoping rules where that was not the case. If there is a bug in gcc, it might be related to that.

Comment: @wolfgang: Good point, that [seems to be it](http://ideone.com/JHcar), as the revised test code shows.

Comment: @Piotr99 On a side note, "using namespace std" seems to be going out of fashion among advocates of good style, anyway.

Comment: This seems to me fixed on mainline (gcc 4.7).

Comment: This fails on gcc-4.6.1 also - so it's a recent fix.  Don't know if it'll be back-ported.

Comment: @wolfgang Thanks for the hint. Is it still recommended to declare "using std::cout" and "using std::endl" in an appropriate scope? I don't see why there would be any harm done with these, as everybody reading C++ should recognize them in the blink of an eye...

Comment: @emsr Good to read it is fixed in gcc 4.7! Anyway, I'm looking forward to that version, as most of the C++11 convenience additions will be implemented by then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename the variable `pair` in your for loop.

It's scope *should* only extend to the end of the `for` loop and therefore not interfere with your 
lambda, but g++ has some code for ancient for-scoping rules where that was not the case, so it can emit better error messages for ancient C++ code.

It looks as if there is a bug in that compatibility code.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's true -- with a different variable name in the for loop it works! Still, I agree with you, it should be restricted to the loop's scope...

Comment: For the record, there is already a gcc bug report: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10852 - the lambda just makes the error message worse.